# Query returns last 11 fiscal years as rows. Can I get use LISTAGG() to convert it to a comma separated list?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have composed this query to return the last 11 fiscal years:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,+3)))-LEVEL+1 
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 11;
```

It returns the following:

[image]

I would like to convert it to a comma-separated VARCHAR2, as follows:

`'2019,2018,2017,2016,2015,2014,2013,2012,2011,2010,2009'`

Is there a way to use `LISTAGG()` for this? Or any other suggestions for a straight PL/SQL query (i.e., a `SELECT` statement; without a `DECLARE BEGIN END;` block)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would compute the values in a subquery and then use `LISTAGG()`:

```
with x as (
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,+3)))-LEVEL+1 as y
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 11
)
select listagg(y, ',') within group (order by y desc) from x
```

Result:

```
LISTAGG(Y,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYYDESC)             
------------------------------------------------------
2019,2018,2017,2016,2015,2014,2013,2012,2011,2010,2009
```

Comment: Thanks, Impaler; That worked! I didn't know about that `WITH` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT LISTAGG(Y, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Y DESC) AS LIS FROM
(SELECT TO_NUMBER(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, +3))) - LEVEL + 
1 AS Y FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 11);
```